# Linux - readarray in awk

Tags: linux, awk

I'm new to shell scritpts. I am trying to load single column file(column1 - numbers) with `readarray` and print length of array. but getting ERROR.

GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

**array.sh**

```
sqlplus -s user/pass@SID.WORLD <<-END > /dev/null

set heading off;
spool /tmp/numbers.txt
select number from table;
COMMIT;
spool off;
END


awk '{
        readarray tn < "/tmp/numbers.txt"
        print $1     #// just checking
        print  ${#tn[@]}   #// getting array length.
}' /tmp/numbers2.txt
```

**ERROR:**

```
awk: cmd. line:3:       print  ${#tn[@]}
awk: cmd. line:3:               ^ syntax error
```

**Update:**

```
I want to use that readarray to populate array and do some operation on array.
```

IF I change `awk` to

```
awk  '{
        readarray tn < "/tmp/numbers.txt"
        print tn;    # // will print blank lines that is equals to actual lines of file
}' /tmp/numbers1.txt
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here exactly? Are you trying to print the first column of `numbers2.txt` and then the length of `numbers.txt` in paired lines?

Comment: awk is not shell, it's a completely separate tool with it's own language. You should not expect to be able to call shell commands directly from awk any more than you could call them from C. If you tell us WHAT you are trying to do (as opposed to HOW you are trying to do whatever it is) with some sample input and expected output, we can help.

Comment: You want to operate on the array in awk? In the shell? What does that sql get involved?

Comment: To Answer: Yes. In shell. To fill-up the file with numbers from DB.

Answer (score 2):

Some alternatives:

just use bash: `readarray tn < "/tmp/numbers.txt"; echo ${#tn[@]}`

awk: `awk 'END {print NR}' /tmp/numbers.txt`

wc: `wc -l < /tmp/numbers.txt`

sql:

```
set heading off;
spool /tmp/numbers.txt
select number from table;
spool off;
select count(number) from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

awk is not shell. `readarray` is a shell command. `${#tn[@]}` is a shell variable evaluation. Neither of those is valid in awk.

I'm not at all clear on what you are trying to do exactly so I can't really begin to suggest a correct approach as such.